# How to tell TypeScript there is no undefined in Array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types, undefined

I have the error: Type (string | undefined)[] is not assignable to type string | string[] | undefined, because my function this.errors get the type string | string[] | undefined. But before to return the array I filtered it with undefined. It means there is no undefined. And the value can be string or undefined. The definition of setErrors return array of errors.
This is my error:[image]

This is my function:

```
    this.setErrors(() => {
      const errors = validators.map(val => val(this.inputValue));
      const filteredErrors = errors.filter(el => el);

      return filteredErrors && filteredErrors.length !== 0 ? filteredErrors : undefined;
    });
```

Validators:

```
const REGEXP_UPPERCASE = /[A-Z]/;
const REGEXP_LOWERCASE = /[a-z]/;
const REGEXP_ONE_DIGIT = /.*[0-9].*/;

export const newPasswordValidators = (args: { min: number; max: number }) => {
  const { min, max } = args;
  return {
    minMaxLength: (value?: string) => value && value.length < min || value.length > max ? 'Not valid length' : undefined,
    requiredToFill: (value?: string) => !value ? 'Required to fill.' : undefined,
    uppercaseLetter: (value?: string) => value && !REGEXP_UPPERCASE.test(value) ? 'Use at least one uppercase letter.' : undefined,
    lowercaseLetter: (value?: string) => value && !REGEXP_LOWERCASE.test(value) ? 'Use at least one lowercase letter.' : undefined,
    atLeastOneDigit: (value?: string) => value && !REGEXP_ONE_DIGIT.test(value) ? 'Use at least one digit.' : undefined,
  };
};
```

Super class method:

```
  public setErrors(errors: string | string[] | undefined | (() => (string | string[] | undefined))) {
    this._errors = errors;
  }
```

Can you tell me please how can I get rid from this error?

Comment: What is `validators`? What is `this.inputValue`? What is the definition of `this.setErrors`?

Comment: Can't return filteredErrors && filteredErrors.length !== 0 ? filteredErrors : undefined; be just be  return filteredErrors.length !== 0 ?

Comment: @jocoders, you still need to add the definition of `this.setErrors` and `validators`

Comment: Validators check the string, setErrors came from the super class

Comment: As I see, you go through validators via `map()`. Your validators can return `undefined` or string with error. It looks like TS filter typing is not smart enough, so you still have (string | undefined)[] after its run. So the best option is typecasting until it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ever hear of typecasting (to be exact, it's more a type assertion in TS due to JS' dynamic nature)? Sounds like this is what you need here, there are two ways to do it which produce basically the same result:

```
const x: string[] = <string[]>strAndUndefinedArr;
const y: string[] = strAndUndefinedArr as string[];
```

This works everywhere, you can also do stuff like

```
functionCall(<string[]>arr); //or functionCall(arr as string[])
```

You can read more on this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

Comment: If you are going to resort to this for such a common error, why use TypeScript? Who knows the runtime errors you are suppressing?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you have two values:

```js
const foo: (string | undefined)[] | undefined = 'hello foo';
const bar: string | string[] | undefined = 'hello bar';
```

As You may have noticed, variable bar can be `string`, whereas variable `foo` can't.
variable `foo` can be an array of strings or undefineds or undefined at all.

Simplier example:

```js
const fn = (arg: string)=>arg;
const result = fn(undefined) // error;
```

You cant pass `undefined` to function which expects `string`

I think you should adjust your types or allow one of your values to be a `string`  type;
Please keep in mind, you can use `any` type or `as` operator, but it is a cheating.

Comment: But I don't do it, because I filtered an array for undefined before to return in. There is no undefined in the array

Comment: Could you please share working example of your code in any online sandbox? It will be much easier to figure out whats going on here